# Pass data from template to django's views.py

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

Right now i'm working on the pagination of the data table at my django's project. And i'm trying to let the user put how many registers are displayed per page, but i'm having troubles passing the number at the selector that i'm using to views.py (where the pagination is), my question is: How to pass the selected number to views.py so it updates the registers?

this is my code:

Template's Selector:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select class="selector" id="estado" name="estado" onchange="post()" style="border-color: #C9C9C9; color:black; height: 25px; width:100px; position:absolute; margin-top:-32px; margin-left:230px;">
        <option  selected style="color:black;">5</option>
        <option   style="color:black;">10</option>
        <option  style="color:black;">25</option>
        <option  style="color:black;">50</option>
        <option  style="color:black;">100</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Views.py:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        inicial = { 'paginas' : 5,
        }
        num = paginaForm(initial = inicial).fields['paginas']
    else:
        num = 5

    riesgos = Riesgos.objects.all() 
    #Paginación  
    paginator = Paginator(riesgos, num)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    index = items.number - 1
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
    end_index = index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
    page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
    context = {'riesgos':riesgos, 'page_range':page_range, 'items':items}
    return render(request,'restapi/listar_riesgo.html', context)
```

Models.py

```
class Paginas(models.Model):
    paginas = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
```

Forms.py:

```
class paginaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Paginas
        fields = [ 
            'paginas',
        ]
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I recommend you pass a GET variable which contain's the user's choice, then you can handle it in your views.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By any chance u know how to do that?

Comment: Change form method to `GET` and submit form on dropdown change i.e. `onchange="this.form.submit()"` and extract data from request in view.

Comment: Nice! i just did it, but it says that integerField can't be parsed to int. Do u know how to fix this please?

Comment: add `value=number_per_page` to each of your `<option>`s. Obviously changing number_per_page for each option

Comment: Still i believe that i'm calling the integerField from the model, which i don't how how to parse to int, and not the selector value itself.